# Visual Basic Problems

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a program that would function as a "shopping list". I have completed all the code and setting it up and what not but when I try and run the program it will not run. I have 0 errors in my code and it will not debug either. There are two programs I am having this problem with. Here is the code for both of the programs.
PROGRAM 1:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Item As String = txtAdd.Text
    Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Item = Me.txtAdd.Text
        Me.lstItems.Items.Add(Item)
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnMoveToList_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMoveToList.Click
        Me.lstItems.Items.Remove(Item)
        Me.lstList.Items.Add(Item)
    End Sub
Private Sub btnMoveToItems_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMoveToItems.Click
    Me.lstList.Items.Remove(Item)
    Me.lstItems.Items.Add(Item)
End Sub
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Me.lstItems.Items.Remove(Item)
End Sub
End Class
```

PROGRAM 2:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim total As Double
    Dim Cost As Double = Me.txtCost.Text
    Dim Number As Integer = Me.txtNumber.Text


    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        total = (Cost * Number)

        If Int32.TryParse(Me.txtCost.Text, Me.txtNumber.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("The total cost of your items is:" & total)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Enter correct numeric values")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am receiving a pop up window that says "An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: The fact that the form won't show usually means a problem in the constructor. Since you haven't shown any constructor code, what happens if you create a new winforms app and run it with no code? It's possible your templates / auto-generated code have become corrupt (although I've never heard of it happening spontaneously). If a new winforms works, try adding your code a block at a time until it breaks. If a new app is also broken, try reinstalling VS

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim Item As String = txtAdd.Text
```

won’t work class-level; `txtAdd` doesn’t refer to your textbox at that point. You can initialize it in `New` instead:

```
Private Item As String

Public Sub New()
    Me.InitializeComponent()
    Me.Item = txtAdd.Text
End Sub
```

Your second form has the same problem, but seeing as you don’t use the two fields in there, you don’t need them. If they should reflect the inputs, use properties instead, e.g.

```
Public ReadOnly Property Cost() As String
    Get
        Return Me.txtCost.Text
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: There's no constructor in the OP's code so the default constructor should be used (which calls `InitializeComponent()`)

Comment: The order of initialization is fields (as seen here) followed by `New()`, so it doesn’t matter that `New()` calls `InitializeComponent()` by default. The error happens before that.

Comment: Did you change all the fields in both your forms?